# jQuery .css function not working when window.location is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location

I have a JavaScript function as:

```
($('.expand').parent().next().children('li')).click(function() {
    $(this).css('background','#aaaaaa');
    window.location=($(this).children('a')).attr('href');    
  });
```

I am getting background color in ios devices but not working in samsung android native browsers.

Did anyone came across this issue. Please advice.

**Edited**

If I use

```
($('.expand').parent().next().children('li')).click(function() {
    $(this).css('background','#aaaaaa');
});
```

without window.location I am getting the background color but I want both bgcolor and redirection

Comment: try with  window.location.href=($(this).children('a')).attr('href');

Comment: Amit Prajapati I have tried it before but no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backgroung-color instead of background:

```
$(this).css({backgroundColor: '#aaaaaa'});
```

or

```
$(this).css('background-color', '#aaaaaa');
```

Comment: #nanor Thanks for your suggestion. But your solution is not working for me. please see my updated question.

Comment: The window.location is invoked before the .css() is done (I know it sounds weird...). Try calling the window.location with setTimeout().

Comment: @aaviss Did it work or not? I couldn't understand from "setTimeout() worked not" :)